# Jquery dynamic fields in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a simple dynamic form where when user press 2 two fields will display and if he press one 1 fields will display

Issue faced :
If user enters 1 , one field is showing but if user deletes the 1 and press 2 instead of 1 the 3 fields showing

HTML CODE

```
<label for="textarea2b">Quantity</label>
<input type="number" name="name2" id="quantitypickup" onkeyup="showdimension()" value="" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="">
<div id="dimshow" class="row">

</div>
```

JS CODE

```
function showdimension() {
    var q = $("#quantitypickup").val();
    var r = $("#dimshow");
    if (q == "0" || q == "" || q == null) {
        r.hide();
        r.html('');
    } else {
        r.show();
        for (var i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            r.append('  <div class="col-xs-6"><label>Item Name ' + (i + 1) + '</label><input type="text" name="name2" id="itemname" onkeyup="" value="" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder=""></div><div class="col-xs-6"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-4"><label>Length</label><input type="number" name="name2"  onkeyup="" value="" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder=""><label style="text-align:center">inches</label></div><div class="col-xs-4"><label>Width</label><input type="number" name="name2"  onkeyup="" value="" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder=""><label style="text-align:center">inches</label></div><div class="col-xs-4"><label>Height</label><input type="number" name="name2" value="" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder=""><label style="text-align:center">inches</label></div></div> </div></div>');
        }
    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: Add `r.html('');` in else block as well before `.append`!

Comment: Thanks it is working

Comment: I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_

Answer (score 0):

clear your html `row` each time user enter a number by `$('.row').html('');`

```js
function showdimension() {
  $('.row').html('');
    var q = $("#quantitypickup").val();
    var r = $("#dimshow");
    if (q == "0" || q == "" || q == null) {
        r.hide();
        r.html('');
    } else {
        r.show();
        for (var i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            r.append('  <div class="col-xs-6"><label>Item Name ' + (i + 1) + '</label><input type="text" name="name2" id="itemname" onkeyup="" value="" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder=""></div><div class="col-xs-6"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-4"><label>Length</label><input type="number" name="name2"  onkeyup="" value="" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder=""><label style="text-align:center">inches</label></div><div class="col-xs-4"><label>Width</label><input type="number" name="name2"  onkeyup="" value="" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder=""><label style="text-align:center">inches</label></div><div class="col-xs-4"><label>Height</label><input type="number" name="name2" value="" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder=""><label style="text-align:center">inches</label></div></div> </div></div>');
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="textarea2b">Quantity</label>
<input type="number" name="name2" id="quantitypickup" onkeyup="showdimension()" value="" data-clear-btn="true" placeholder="">
<div id="dimshow" class="row">

</div>
```

Comment: Or use `.html` only once instead of troubling `DOM` in a `loop`